# How do I split and name the text file (based on the no. of lines of content) for bigdata?

Tags: text-processing, file-management

I had a 1000's of text files on a Linux machine, and each text file's name has a prefix (`OG00`*) and contains 9 unique IDs. I want to create one text file for each of these IDs with text file names - `OG0012637_1.txt, OG0012637_2.txt, OG0012637_3.txt, OG0012637_4.txt, OG0012637_5.txt....OG0012637_9.txt`

```
Input:
```

```
$ cat OG0012637.txt
        TRINITY_DN9932_c0_g2_i1.p1
        TRINITY_DN17663_c0_g1_i1.p1
        TRINITY_DN6645_c0_g1_i2.p1
        TRINITY_DN2462_c0_g1_i2.p1
        TRINITY_DN19713_c3_g1_i2.p1
        TRINITY_DN4587_c0_g1_i1.p1
        TRINITY_DN4405_c0_g1_i1.p1
        TRINITY_DN7191_c1_g2_i1.p1
        TRINITY_DN1740_c0_g1_i2.p1
```

Desired output files:

```
$ cat OG0012637_1.txt
 TRINITY_DN9932_c0_g2_i1.p1
$ cat OG0012637_2.txt
 TRINITY_DN17663_c0_g1_i1.p1
$ cat OG0012637_3.txt
 TRINITY_DN6645_c0_g1_i2.p1
$ cat OG0012637_4.txt
 TRINITY_DN2462_c0_g1_i2.p1
$ cat OG0012637_5.txt
 TRINITY_DN19713_c3_g1_i2.p1
$ cat OG0012637_6.txt
 TRINITY_DN4587_c0_g1_i1.p1
$ cat OG0012637_7.txt
 TRINITY_DN4405_c0_g1_i1.p1
$ cat OG0012637_8.txt
 TRINITY_DN7191_c1_g2_i1.p1
$ cat OG0012637_9.txt
 TRINITY_DN1740_c0_g1_i2.p1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Please tell us what help you expect from the Stackexchange community. If you expect "do my work for free", I can predict that you won't gain many friends. In other words, try solving the problem yourself and tell us where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the GNU implementation of split, then with awk:

```
awk '
  FNR==1 {
    basename = substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4)
  } 
  {
    outfile = basename "_" FNR ".txt"; print > outfile; close(outfile)
  }
' OG*.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The tool/utility that's made for such tasks is **split**. And the `GNU` version has options that fit your use case to a tee:

```
for f in OG00*.txt; do
split -l1 -a1 -e --additional-suffix=.txt  --numeric-suffixes=1  "$f" "${f%????}_" 
done
```

**Output**

```
.
├── OG0012637_1.txt
├── OG0012637_2.txt
├── OG0012637_3.txt
├── OG0012637_4.txt
├── OG0012637_5.txt
├── OG0012637_6.txt
├── OG0012637_7.txt
├── OG0012637_8.txt
├── OG0012637_9.txt
└── OG0012637.txt
```

- `-l1` shall split the files one per line.
- `-a1` shall keep the number length to single digit, since we have only 9 generated files to deal with.
- `--numeric-suffixes` shall start
  numberingg the output files from 1 rather than the default 0.
- `--additional-suffix` shall append .txt to the output files rather than the default nothing.
- The prefix is the basename followed by an underscore rather than the default xa.

Comment: Thanks worked for me.